# Parameterization in Snowflake UDF

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm currently trying to refactor some SQL logic in Snowflake to improve readability and reduce repeated code by using UDF's.

Here is the UDF I'm trying to create:

```sql
create or replace function myfunc(var1 varchar, var2 varchar)
returns table (result int)
as 
$$
select var1 from table1
where var2 = 1
$$;

select * from table(myfunc(column1, column2));
```

I want `var1` and `var2` to be two column names in `table1` but not sure how to do that in SQL/Snowflake UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake allows to use `IDENTIFIER` and variables to achieve similar effect:

```
 SET (VAR1, VAR2) = ('my_col1', 'my_col2');
 
 SELECT IDENTIFIER($VAR1)
 FROM table_name
 WHERE IDENTIFIER($VAR2) = 1;
```

However this kind of syntax cannot be wrapped with UDTF. To parametrize column list/table name dynamic SQL(stored procedure) could be used.

---

Sidenote: The pattern used in question:

```
select * from table(myfunc(column1, column2));
```

is called **Polymorphic Table Function(PTF)** and it is defined in
[ISO/IEC TR 19075-7:2017
Information technology — Database languages — SQL Technical Reports — Part 7: Polymorphic table functions in SQL](https://www.iso.org/standard/69776.html)

It allows to shape the result's structure during runtime and provides greater flexibility. An example could be [SELECT * EXCEPT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49015504/5070879)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403809/how-to-write-dynamic-queries-in-snowflake-user-defined-functions) it's not possible in a UDF, and there are no examples in the [Snowflake UDF docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql.html) beyond plain (i.e. non-dynamic) SQL.

But it *is* possible as a stored procedure if that's an option for you. The [Snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#dynamically-creating-a-sql-statement) have examples of the syntax (and [tips/warnings](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#label-sql-injection) about SQL injection).